# How to change color of a shape after a time x?

Tags: time, colors, swiftui

Sorry if it's a simple fix, I am a still bit new to swift/swiftui
I have been trying to accomplish a change of color after a second.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var hasTimeElapsed = false
    
    var colorCircle: [Color] = [.red, .green]
      
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(self.colorCircle.randomElement()!)
            .frame(width: 100,
                   height: 100)
            .onAppear(perform: delayCircle)
    }
    
    private func delayCircle() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.hasTimeElapsed = true
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use the `hasTimeElapsed` variable. Instead you can add a `@State` variable to store your current colour and set it in `delayCircle()`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var colorCircle: [Color] = [.red, .green]

    @State var currentColor = Color.red
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(currentColor)
            .frame(width: 100,
                   height: 100)
            .onAppear(perform: delayCircle)
    }

    private func delayCircle() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.currentColor = self.colorCircle.randomElement()!
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you want to start with a random colour (instead of `@State var currentColor = Color.red`) you can set it in init:

```
@State var currentColor: Color

init() {
    _currentColor = .init(initialValue: self.colorCircle.randomElement()!)
}
```

---

**UPDATE due to OP's comment**

If you want to set your circle colour in a loop you can use a `Timer`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var colorCircle: [Color] = [.red, .green]

    @State var currentColor: Color = .red

    // firing every 1 second
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(currentColor)
                .frame(width: 100,
                       height: 100)
            Button("Stop timer") {
                self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel() // <- stop the timer
            }
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in // <- when the timer fires perfom some action (here `randomizeCircleColor()`)
            self.randomizeCircleColor()
        }
    }

    private func randomizeCircleColor() {
        self.currentColor = self.colorCircle.randomElement()!
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I asked the wrong question. It did not work yet. I want, that the Circle changes the color automatically, by his own, in a loop until an external trigger stops it. Could sombody help

Comment: @Alen Yes, you didn't specify this in your question. But I added a solution for your problem in my answer.